# Xcode 15 error : No .app bundles found in the package

Tags: python, ios, xcode, kivy, toolchain

I created a Kivy test app to access IPhone files.

I have an error on trying to upload the app to AppStore.

The upload summary:
[image: upload summary]

The error:
[image: error]

The .app file is not generated by the build process. Why?

My environment :

- MacBook Pro with M3 Pro
- MacOS Sonoma 14.3
- Xcode 15.2
- Command Line Tools installed with Xcode 15.2
- Python 3.11 with PyEnv
- kivy-ios with toolchain installed in pyenv

I tried to build on older versions of MacOS and Xcode.

I tried to upload the app for TestFlight only.

I tried to upload the app with the Transporter app.